# Why would you subtract 1 from the Width and Height properties of a Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have the following code:

```
public static double[][] GetRgbProjections(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var width = bitmap.Width - 1;
    var height = bitmap.Height - 1;

    var horizontalProjection = new double[width];
    var verticalProjection = new double[height];

    var bitmapData1 = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Does anyone know what the `bitmap.Width - 1` is for? Also the `bitmap.Height - 1;`? Why would you subtract 1 from each of those property values?

Comment: Not enough information... The arrays are not even used here in the piece of code...

Comment: You probably need to ask the author of that method that question. Perhaps the image is to be shrunk by 1 pixel in both dimensions?

Comment: Not enough context in this code, perhaps `horizontalProjection` and `verticalProjection` are computed from two pixels?

Comment: you should post more code (e.g. when `horizontalProjection` and `verticalProjection` are used)

Answer (score 2):

The values returned by the `Width` and `Height` properties are **exclusive**, meaning that the pixel with the coordinates (Width, Height) lies immediately *outside* of the bounds of the bitmap.

Thus, if you want to iterate through the pixels, you need to subtract one to get the correct number of rows or columns.

Of course, it's hard to tell much more. The values aren't used again in the section of code you've shown.

Comment: I'm confused, a 640 x 480 bitmap returns 640 for Width, and 480 for Height, so how are these values exclusive?  (The RECT struct from Win API is exclusive however).

Comment: @Chris: I'm not sure I know how else to explain it. The rows and columns of a bitmap are zero-indexed, so if you're going to loop through them, you'll need to subtract one from the width and height. There is no pixel location (640, 480). Like I said, the code in the question doesn't actually *show* how those variables are used, but this is the reason I've subtracted 1 from the width and height of a bitmap numerous times.

Answer (score 1):

No. We will never know what the purpose of subtracting 1 from the bitmap width because we do not know the context of `bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is to make the array indices match up with the row and height values of the bitmap. Consider:

You have a 2x2 pixel bitmap. It has 4 total pixels, 2 for both width and height. If you want to iterate through it, you need to iterate from 0 to 1 inclusive in both directions (width and height), but if you go by bitmap pixels, you will be iterating between 1 and 2 which will result in an index out of bounds.

Personally, I would have not subtracted one from the width and height *variables*, but only subtracted when iterating through the pixel array to prevent confusion.